# My book calls an expression $f(z)$ when it's not a function of $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is :

> Show that the function $f(z)=2xy+i(x^2-y^2)$ is nowhere analytic

As it turns out the expression on the RHS is $i\bar z^2$. Then how come the book writes it as $f(z)$?
If it were a function of $z$, we should have an expression for it in terms of $z$. But I can't seem to find such an expression.

Comment: It _is_ a function of $z$ - with $z$ being piped through the complex conjugate first.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I don't understand

Comment: They split $z$ in real and complex parts by writing $z=x+iy$.

Comment: You clearly understand that $f(z)=i\bar{z}^{2}=2xy+i(x^{2}-y^{2})$ where $x$ is the real part of $z$ and $y$ is the imaginary part.  So, what is that you actually want to understand?

Comment: I think @HritRoy that you should tell us what you think a function *is*.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You seem to think a function is an "expression".

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.

Comment: So for instance you wouldn't call $x^2$ a function of $x$, because it has a square in it?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier none of what I said implies that

Comment: Yes, when you say that $\overline{z}$ is not a function of $z$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier no. $x^2$ is an expression involving $x$. $\bar z$ does not involve $z$ which threw me off. As I said before, it was my mistake.

Comment: Another way to look at it: $x=\Re(z)$ and $y=\Im(z)$

Comment: "$\bar z$ does not involve $z$..."! Think again what is a function.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I meant that $\bar z$ cannot be written as an expression in $z$

Comment: @HritRoy, *wrong* idea. BTW, $e^z$ is an "expression in $z$"?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla First of all, I already said that I understood my mistake. I was only explaining what I said in my previous comments. Doesn't mean I am still sticking to it. And secondly, $e^z$ is raising a number to the power of $z$ or can be seen as an infinite series involving $z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be totally strict (indeed, needlessly pedantic), the problem would be posed as:

> Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $f(z(x, y)) := 2xy+i(x^2-y^2)$. Show that $f$ is nowhere analytic.

where $z: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ is defined by $z(x,y) := x + i y$.

Then, for instance, the conjugate function is $z \mapsto \bar{z}$, or strictly $z(x, y) \mapsto \overline{z(x,y)}$, given by $x + i y \mapsto x - i y$.

We may legally define a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by defining its values on the image of $z$, because $z$ is bijective.

Comment: But now you've got a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not on $\mathbb{C}$. I think that it is functions on $\mathbb{C}$ which are/are not analytic.

Comment: @ancientmathematician No, $f$ is $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. It's $z$ which bijects $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Perhaps I understand what you mean; I'll rephrase to make that distinction clearer.

Comment: But you need the inverse of the bijection. $f(z):=\text{re}(z)\text{im}(z) -$ etc etcc

Comment: @ancientmathematician I added a final sentence; does this make it better for you?

Comment: Obviously we're not in deep disagreement. It just seems to me that $f(g(x,y))$ under the usual conventions is a function of two variables not just one.